# How to transform every element of numpy array into an array of size N filled with the element?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array `a` the shape of which is (m, n).
I want to transform this array into an array `b` with shape (m, n, l), where:

```
b[i,j].length == l
b[i,j,k] == a[i,j]

0 <= i < m
0 <= j < n
0 <= k < l
```

For example:

```
m = 2
n = 3
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

If `l = 2`, then `b`:

```
b = [[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]],[[4,4],[5,5],[6,6]]]
```

How can I do it? Is there an easy one-line solution?

Comment: The one-liner `b = np.repeat(a[:, :, np.newaxis], l, axis=2)` works.

Comment: Though note that this solution requires `a` to be a numpy array, not just a list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it:

```
np.repeat(a, l).reshape(a.shape + (-1,))
```